# Excel Import XML specific Nodes

Tags: xml, excel

I tried to import some specific XML Nodes into Excel 2010. But I get some Errors. I want create a table with the content from the XML Node "Item" to make it easier to read. But there are some problems, the Error which is defined later and that I don't work often with XML. My other idea is to create a RegEx to import the Nodes but I think that's not a good way to do this because some of these Data could be huge and I think that it would be slow with RegEx.

I would be thankful for any ideas to get my script to work.

**Here is the code:**

```vb
Sub read_XML()
    Dim objXML As Object, ListNode As Object, oNode As Object
    Dim sPath$
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim nRow&, nCol&

    ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path

    sPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("XML-File (*.xml), *.xml")
    If sPath = CStr(False) Then Exit Sub

    With Tabelle1
    Set rng = .Range("A:J")
    rng.Rows(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Clear
    End With

    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")


    If objXML.Load(sPath) Then
    Set ListNode = objXML.SelectNodes("/SAMPLESET/SUMMARY/ITEM") 'all ITEMs
    nRow = 2 'first Row
    For Each oNode In ListNode
        For nCol = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If Not oNode.SelectSingleNode(rng.Cells(1, nCol)) Is Nothing Then
                rng.Cells(nRow, nCol) = oNode.SelectSingleNode(rng.Cells(1,   nCol)).Text
            End If
        Next
        nRow = nRow + 1 'next Row
    Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**Here is the error:**

> the expression does not return a node

**And here the XML:**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <SAMPLESET>
        <CODEID>066</CODEID>
        <SAMPLEID/>
        <OPERATORID/>
        <PROGRAMNAME>myIso</PROGRAMNAME>
        <ENDSERIE>1</ENDSERIE>
        <SUMMARY>
            <ITEM>
                <PROPERTYID>1701</PROPERTYID>
                <PROPERTYNAME>Force CD</PROPERTYNAME>
                <UNIT>N</UNIT>
                <MEAN>180.0</MEAN>
                <MEDIAN>185.0</MEDIAN>
                <COV>17.0</COV>
                <STD>15.0</STD>
                <MIN>176.0</MIN>
                <MAX>189.0</MAX>
                <NOVALUES>2</NOVALUES>
                <VALUES>181.2,176.0,189.0</VALUES>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <PROPERTYID>3701</PROPERTYID>
                <PROPERTYNAME>Force CD</PROPERTYNAME>
                <UNIT>N</UNIT>
                <MEAN>380.0</MEAN>
                <MEDIAN>385.0</MEDIAN>
                <COV>37.0</COV>
                <STD>35.0</STD>
                <MIN>376.0</MIN>
                <MAX>389.0</MAX>
                <NOVALUES>2</NOVALUES>
                <VALUES>381.2,376.0,389.0</VALUES>
            </ITEM>
        </SUMMARY>
    </SAMPLESET>
```

I don't get what's wrong, any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the contents of your cells. For any value in `rng.Cells(1, nCol)`, we don't know what is being searched for in the XML. Please provide more information and possibly a self-contained example.